# Ineqaulity $\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\mathbb 1_{(0,1)}(y)\ dS(y)\le \int_{\partial B(0,1)}1\ dS(y)$

Tags: integration, inequality

> $\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\mathbb 1_{B(0,1)}(y)\ dS(y)\le \int_{\partial B(0,1)}1\ dS(y)$ for any $x\in\mathbb R^3, r>0$

How can I shove  the above inequality ? Is the RHS area of the ball with radius $1$ and LHS partial area of the ball with radius $t$ and center $x$ s.t. it is contained in the ball $B(0,1)$ as in the picture below ?

[second area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Pwe.jpg)

Why it cannot be greater than the first area, it looks obvious but is there a more rigorous proof ?

Comment: What is $ \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)} $? The indicator function of the closed ball with center $ (0,0,0) $ and radius $ 1 $?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore sorry fixed